# CSS opacity wont work inside li on hover

Tags: html, css, opacity

opacity:1; seems not to work when i hover on the link,although commands like background:red seems to work.Can anyone explain why is that and how to make opacity work?

CSS:

```
.secondBlock{
    border-bottom: solid black 1px;
    height:260px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.secondBlock:hover li{
    opacity:0.5;}

ul li a:hover{
    background:red;
    opacity:1;
}


/*.secondBlock li:hover{*/
/*opacity:1.0;*/
/*}*/
```

HTML:

```
<div class="secondBlock">
<ul>
    <li><a href="" class="secondLinks secondLink1"><img src="images/i1.png" class="imageList">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="secondLinks secondLink2"><img src="images/i2.png" class="imageList">Служба</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="secondLinks secondLink3"><img src="images/i3.png" class="imageList">Рендзина</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="secondLinks secondLink4"><img src="images/i4.png" class="imageList">Солеперенос</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="secondLinks secondLink5"><img src="images/i5.png" class="imageList">Медиапланировние</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="secondLinks secondLink6"><img src="images/i6.png" class="imageList">Таргетирование</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="secondLinks secondLink7"><img src="images/i7.png" class="imageList">Позиционирование</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="secondLinks secondLink8"><img src="images/i8.png" class="imageList">Медиамикс</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="secondLinks secondLink9"><img src="images/i9.png" class="imageList">Законодательство</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="secondLinks secondLink10"><img src="images/i10.png" class="imageList">Жеода</a></li>
</ul>
```

UPDATE:
     `

```
.secondBlock:hover a{
    opacity:0.5;
 }
 ul li a:hover{

      background:red;
      opacity:1;
 }
```

`

Comment: Your `opacity: 1` is referring to the `a` element, whereas your `opacity: 0.5` is on the `li` element.

Comment: @Santi even that i changed it now,it still doesnt work :/

Comment: Post your updated code please.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/vj928p3a/1/ - Take a look at this, it's a quick example I made of what I think you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS opacity property is relative to the parents then `opacity:X;` for the children is equals to `opacity:X*{parentOpacity};` an example:

```
.parent {
  opacity:0.5;
}
.children {
  opacity:0.5; /* this is equals to 0.5*0.5 so 0.25 */
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/v5zpv7jm/) to explain it.

Documentation by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity):

> The value applies to the element as a whole, including its contents, even though the value is not inherited by child elements. Thus, an element and its contained children all have the same opacity relative to the element's background, even if the element and its children have different opacities relative to one another.

```css
.parent {
  opacity:0.5;
}
.children {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
}
#children1 {
  opacity:0.5; /* 0.5 of the parent */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="children" id="children1">

</div>
<div class="children" id="children2">

</div>
</div>
```

**SOLUTION:**

Since you want to change the link opacity you can use `color:rgba(0,0,0,x);` instead.

Then:

```
.parent {
  color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* opacity:0.5; */
}
.children {
  color:rgba(0,0,0,1); /* opacity:1; */
}
```

Also you have to change the `img` opacity when you hover the `a`.

Working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/fbm2682z/2/).

```css
.secondBlock {
  border-bottom: solid black 1px;
  height: 260px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.secondBlock a {
  color:rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

.secondBlock:hover li a {
  color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.secondBlock:hover li a img {
  opacity:0.5;
}

.secondBlock ul li a:hover {
  color:rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
.secondBlock ul li a:hover > img {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="secondBlock">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="" class="secondLinks secondLink6"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/32/32" class="imageList">Таргетирование</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" class="secondLinks secondLink7"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/32/32" class="imageList">Позиционирование</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" class="secondLinks secondLink8"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/32/32" class="imageList">Медиамикс</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Because ".secondBlock li" is the parent

Comment: i see,then how would i fix it?logically i would need a value more than one,2 ideally

Comment: color:rgba(0,0,0,x); would change only the transparency of the letters,not the pictures as well.Have tried it already ;)

Comment: change the color of the link AND the opacity of the <img> (i'll update)

Answer (score 0):

Opacity of an element also depends on its parent element. So, picking color using rgba() would be helpful which helps to select color as well as its opacity. Try with below code:

```
.secondBlock{
border-bottom: solid black 1px;
height:260px;
text-decoration: none;}

.secondBlock:hover li{
opacity:0.5;}


ul li a:hover{
background-color:rgba(255,0,0,1);}
```

Comment: That wouldnt change the transparency of the images in the link ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are giving opacity two different values. The first styling implicitly applies to the link tag so as the second styling directly applies to the same link tag. Try commenting out one of the styles.

Comment: Nope, i am applying 0.5 opacity to all the links inside the div while on hover,and after try to apply 1 opacity on the specific link that i am hover